# Recommended branch

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kernel, 15.04

I am on 14.04 and I was trying to solve my weak wireless connection (download 1Mbs vs 30 Mbs wired) problem using this tread.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219952

by doing the following command
Try these steps with the Realtek card (updated driver and module parameters:

Code:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -r firmware/* /lib/firmware
echo "options rtl8188ee ips=0 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf
```

however,after running the code `make` in the terminal, i got this message

> Recommended branch is ubuntu-15.04 based on your kernel version
>   (3.19.0-25-generic) Should I switch it to ubuntu-15.04 for you? 
>   (y/n):

Does it mean that it will upgrade my OS 14.04 to 15.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04.3 and 15.04 have same kernel version 3.19.

The Realtek driver detected that kernel and suggests to install the driver from a different branch that will work with this kernel.

So just install the driver from that branch. That will not upgrade your system.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your answer gave me the insurance to proceed and it worked.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; a sidenote:

```
$ apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Will install kernel version 3.19

```
$ apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

Will install kernel version 3.16 - giving this result

```
$ lsb_release -a && uname -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
Linux wkbox 3.16.0-46-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 16:27:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Neither of the above will leave 14.04 using the 3.13 series of kernels.

I assume all to be with active updates coming in (I'm seeing that on 3.16 series).

References: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

... these seems not reflect the above though.